# Laravel Policy not working on route middleware

Tags: laravel, routes, authorization, middleware, policy

I have a `NotificationPolicy` with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Notification;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class NotificationPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function update(User $user, Notification $notification)
    {
        return $user->id === $notification->user_id;
    }
}
```

I have registered this properly by adding this to the `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
protected $policies = [
    Notification::class => NotificationPolicy::class,
];
```

I have this so that only the logged in user can update their notification by doing things such as setting the `archived_at` value or `read_at` value to the current timestamp. The policy does work if I use it in the controller, i.e.;

```
class ArchiveItemController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Notification $notification)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $notification);
        $notification->markAsArchived();

        return redirect()->route('inbox.index')->with('success', 'Item has been archived');
    }
}
```

However I don't want to use them in the controllers and would prefer to use them in my routes file. So I have removed this line `$this->authorize('update', $notification);` from the controller and I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Route::prefix('inbox')->middleware(['auth', 'can:employee'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/notification/{notification}/archive', 'User\Account\Inbox\ArchiveItemController')
       ->name('inbox.item.archive')
       ->middleware('can:update', 'notification');
});
```

I've even ran the following but they don't make a difference:

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-middleware) it would be: `->middleware('can:update,notification')`

Comment: Thank you very much Remul. I had made a mistake in that I had `->middleware('can:update', 'notification')` when as you correctly say it is meant to be `->middleware('can:update,notification')` - I had to run the following for the changes to take effect:
`php artisan cache:clear &&
php artisan config:clear &&
php artisan route:clear &&
php artisan view:clear &&
php artisan clear-compiled &&
composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your middleware declaration is not correct.

You will have to change `'can:update', 'notification'` to `'can:update,notification'` for it to work:

So in the end you would have the following:

```
Route::prefix('inbox')->middleware(['auth', 'can:employee'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/notification/{notification}/archive', 'User\Account\Inbox\ArchiveItemController')
        ->name('inbox.item.archive')
        ->middleware('can:update,notification');
});
```

If you have cached the routes, you will have to run `php artisan route:clear` for the changes to take effect.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-middleware):

> Laravel includes a middleware that can authorize actions before the
> incoming request even reaches your routes or controllers. By default,
> the `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize` middleware is assigned the
> `can` key in your `App\Http\Kernel` class. Let's explore an example of
> using the `can` middleware to authorize that a user can update a blog
> post:

```
use App\Post;

Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');
```

> In this example, we're passing the `can` middleware two arguments. The
> first is the name of the action we wish to authorize and the second is
> the route parameter we wish to pass to the policy method. In this
> case, since we are using [implicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding), a `Post` model will be
> passed to the policy method. If the user is not authorized to perform
> the given action, a HTTP response with a `403` status code will be
> generated by the middleware.